# How to evaluate an algorithm running time in a specific processor?

Tags: complexity-theory, dijkstra, processor

I am using quagga routing suite in an embeded processor. The most time consuming part is the shortest path first(spf, Dijkstra) calculation. Since quagga uses a priority queue, so the computational complexity is O(E*log2(V)) where E is the number of edges and V is the number of vertices.
I have measured the running time of spf calculation in the embeded processor and the result is 10 millisecond when E=1 and V=2. 
How can I evaluate the running time of spf calculation when V=800 and E=1600 given O(E*log2(V)) without real measurement which is not practical?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The point of Big-Oh is its independent of any execution model or computer. There is no way to know what the time would be, though you could guess.

Comment: Consider how E and log2(V) change as the constants grow. This sounds like possibly a school exercise, in which case that approximation may be all you can do, but if you need an accurate estimate for real use, you should also take other measurements nearer the target size. Sometimes the real runtime curve differs from the ideal one, e.g. with discontinuities each time the data outgrows a level of the cache/memory hierarchy.

Comment: The actual running time I want to know need not to be very acurate, e.g. about 10^2 milliseconds order or several seconds order or 10^1 seconds order or 10^2 seconds order or even bigger. One way to evaluate is use the complexity expression to estimate. Is there a method to do this since I have measure the runnning time in small V and E?  If this method is impossible then another way maybe using simulation approach. For example, use a computer to simulate the 799 nodes and connect the real embebed processor to computer, and then make a measurement.